# Who/where has the advocado genome been sequenced?

Tags: genetics

I have read several places that the genome of the advocado has been sequenced in mexico but i am not sure at what university or persons involved.

Comment: Although it does not matter much for this question, please never just say `I have read several places` without correctly referring to where you read that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for genome sequences at the National Center for Biotechnology Information (NCBI) site.

Here is a link to *Persea americana* (avocado) from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/?term=avocado). It states on the page the submitter for the genome was Hainan University.

Comment: I found all the sequences they did here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/wgs/?display=contigs&page=1   However they are 5000 different short sequences.  How to combine them or view them in a searchable manner?

Comment: @Dale            You can access the entire genome via: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/wgs/?val=NXHZ01 and then go to the Downloads tab and you can download the FASTA file. This will have all the 5000 contigs together in a ~130MB file. If you do not have software to open the file type, you can change it to a .txt file and open it that way, although you might want to use a good text editor for that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format